# How can I get Tab to cycle through org-mode grandchildren after children?

Tags: org-mode, cycling

With the pointer on a heading, <kbd>Tab</kbd> will
[cycle](https://orgmode.org/manual/Global-and-local-cycling.html)
visibility, revealing children.

```
,-> FOLDED -> CHILDREN -> SUBTREE --.
'-----------------------------------'
```

Is there a way to cycle through grandchildren as well, possibly
with <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> as well for symmetry?

```
,-> FOLDED -> CHILDREN -> GRANDCHILDREN -> SUBTREE --.
'----------------------------------------------------'
```

Comment: Not that I know of - sorry.

Comment: You *can* fold/unfold to level 3 though with `M-: (org-fold-hide-sublevels 3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit for this answer: NickD

It is not currently (2023, v29.0) possible to cycle through grandchildren.

If you want to display subsection titles, but not unfold what is below them, use `M-: (org-fold-hide-sublevels 3)`.